# Url de la imágen reemplazada con src(unknown)

Tags: django, django-urls

estoy intentando mostrar una imágen de un modelo y estoy teniendo problemas para poder hacer que agarre la url de la misma.

En el navegador aparece la imágen con src(unknown)

Al principio pensaba que era un problema con la obtención de la url pero en la python shell aparece bien

[image: Python shell con la url de la imágen]

Dejo como tengo configurada la url para la obtención de media por si ayuda.
Desde ya agradezco cualquier ayuda!

Template html

```
{% block title %} Portfolio | {% endblock title %}

{% load static %}
{% block bg_img %}{% static 'core/img/portfolio-bg.jpg' %}{% endblock bg_img %}

{% block content %}
<h2>Mis trabajos</h2>

{% comment %} Proyectos {% endcomment %}
    {% for project in projects %}
        <!-- Proyecto -->
        <div class="row project">   
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 offset-lg-1">
                <img src="{{project.image.url}}">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-8">
                <h2 class="section-heading title">{{project.title}}</h2>   
                <p>{{project.description}}</p>
                {% if project.link %}
                    <p><a href="{{project.link}}">Más información</a></p>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock content %}
```

Url.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from core import views as core_views
from portfolio import views as portfolio_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', core_views.home, name='home'),
    path('portfolio', portfolio_views.portfolio, name='portfolio'),
    path('contacto', core_views.contacto, name='contacto'),
    path('about', core_views.about, name='about'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
] 

""" Add path for media (not in production env) """
if settings.DEBUG:
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
""" Para agregar nombre personalizado a los campos: verbose_name
Clase meta para poder cambiar los datos default del modelo
Clase __str__ para cambiar el título que muestra django de los modelos
Para cambiar la carpeta en la que se almacena el multimedia se usa upload_to """

class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Título')
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name='Descripción')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='projects', height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=None, verbose_name='Imágen')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Fecha de creación')
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False, verbose_name='Fecha de actualización')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Proyecto'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Proyectos'
        ordering = ['created']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 0):

Al final mi error fue en la vista en vez de usar Project.objects.all(), estaba usando Project.objects.all().values() porque pensaba que así obtenía los valores. 3hs por eso jajajaja.